# Querying nested documents using Mongoose (MongoDB)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am starting out with mongodb and having hard time trying to query nested documents. I have two schemas:

```
var LinkSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    url: String,
    name: String
});

var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    links: [LinkSchema]
});
```

As you can see, I am just tying to build a simple bookmarking tool. Each user has a name and a collection of links. Each link has a name and a url.

Now, what I am trying to do is for example, see if a link already exists in someone's links array. I would like to be able to do something like this (Trying to get vlad's link collection and then see if the query link already belongs to the collection or not):

```
app.get("/:query", function(req, res){
  User.findOne({"name":"vlad"}, function(err, user){
    user.links.find({"url":req.params.query}, function(err, foundLinks){
      if(foundLinks){
        res.send("link already exists!");
      } else {
        res.send("link doesn't exist!");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Of course, this code doesn't work, because apparently I can't do a "user.links.find()". I guess I can just do a user.links.map to extract only urls and then run a membership query against it. But I think this would be far from the right solution. There's gotta be a way to do something like this natively using DB queries. Can someone help? Thank you!

Answer (score 79, accepted):

You can query an embedded document in mongoose like this

```
   User.find({'links.url':req.params.query}, function(err, foundUsers){
      // ---
   });
```

and to find the links that belong to the user "vlad", you can write

```
   User.find({name:'vlad','links.url':req.params.query}, function(err, foundUsers){
      // ---
   });
```

This will do the trick.

Comment: why the returned parameter is `foundLinks` and not `foundUsers` ?

Comment: Could you answer to @geevee comment ?

Comment: @RémiBecheras @geevee  It should be `foundUsers`, but i just used the code the OP had originally posted.. it was `foundLinks` there.. you can check that :)

Comment: Thank you. We asked because if it was right, we missed something big.... I just edited your post to fixing it

Comment: I would really love to see mongodb native driver version of these two queries.

Comment: can i use multiple conditions? when querying inside an embed doc?

Comment: is this only available specific version of mongoose?

Comment: Thanks for this answer but those queries returns Users and not only Link as asked by @vlad. Is there a way to retreive only Links ?

Answer (score 3):

To find a specific link that belongs to a specific user you can do this

```
User.find({name:'vlad','links.url':req.params.query}, { 'links.$': 1 },  function(err, foundUsers){
      // ---
   });
```

Comment: What is the `{ 'links.$' : 1 }` part called? I'm looking for the documentation on this feature. I'm assuming it's saying to just return the one nested document?

Comment: Adding to this, `const foundLinks = foundUsers.links[0]`